# Reading fstream returns junk

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a text file that contains only strings. It is compiling and opening but when reading it just displays junk that has no bearing to the characters in the file at all.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

fstream myfile;
char* input;

void main(void)
{
    myfile.open("H://fstream_test.txt", fstream::in);
    if(myfile.fail()) 
    {
        cout<<"error"; exit(0);
    }
    cout<<"file is open";

    int beginning = myfile.tellg();
    myfile.seekg(0, fstream::end);
    int end = myfile.tellg();
    int size = end-beginning;
    cout<<size; //returns 15

    input = new char[size];
    myfile.read(input,size);

    cout<<input;
    //returns junk

    //for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        //cout<<input[i];
    //returns the same;
}
```

end edited to:

```
input = new char[size];
    myfile.seekg(0, fstream::beg);
    while(!myfile.eof())
    {
        myfile.read(input,size);
    }

    cout<<input;
    system("pause");
```

Comment: input = new char[size]; No delete[]. That's a memory leak. Use a standard library container instead.

Answer (score 2):

You seek to the end of the file before trying to read:

```
myfile.seekg(0, fstream::end);
```

To make this work, you'll have to seek to the beginning first.

Also note that `myfile.read()` will not append a NUL terminator.

Comment: Its reading the text but there is still a lot of junk coming afterwards. I've tried including a while !eof loop but that didn't work. I'll show the edited code above.

Comment: @MatthewParker: There's no NUL terminator. You have to add it yourself (making sure you've allocated space for it). Alternatively, put the text into a `std::string`.

Comment: As in I have to add the NUL terminator to the text file "0". If I save this as a binary will this happen automatically?